# odoo: can't find '__main__' module al crear nuevo módulo

Tags: python, windows, odoo

estoy tratando de crear un nuevo módulo en [odoo-16](/questions/tagged/odoo-16) mediante el comando

> "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo\cli" scaffold custom_crm "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo\addons"

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
 C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\python\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Program Files\\Odoo 16.0.20230705\\server\\odoo\\cli'
```

alguien sabe que puedo hacer para crear mi módulo?